# Marketcap increase from when I bought

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I have the code that enters the trade if the marketcap of the cryptocurrency decreases by 3%. How would I change this so that it exits the trade when the marketcap increases/decreases by X% **from the price at which it entered the trade**?

```
change = input(3, title = "MktCap 1D percent change")/100.0     // <=== Change the value of 3 to whatever percentage you would like
rr(s, bb)=>(s - s[bb])/s
signal(s, bb)=>
    rr = rr(s, bb)
    //long = rr >= change       // <=== For a percentage increase
    long = rr <= -change        // <=== For a percentage decrease
    [long]
[long] = request.security("CRYPTOCAP:"+syminfo.basecurrency, "D", signal(close,1))

if (long and timePeriod)
    strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you mean **market cap value change by X%**:

```
cap = request.security("CRYPTOCAP:" + syminfo.basecurrency, "D", close) // store market cap first for more flexibility  

capChange(base, newVal) => na(base) ? 0 : (newVal - base)/base  

var float lastCap = na // "var" declaration to keep the value of lastCap over bars
...
// your entry logic...
if true  
    lastCap := cap // we enter the trade with this cap
    strategy.entry("Long", ...)
...  
if strategy.opentrades > 0 and math.abs(capChange(lastCap, cap)) >= change
    lastCap := na
    strategy.close("Long") // "Long" is the ID you chose for your entry trade that you want to close
...
```

You should store your cap value separately so that you can use it for "go long" / "go short" or "exit" evaluations. You can include further checks in your conditional if you want to close short/long which one etc. it depends on your needs. **It's just a simple solution.**

If you mean entry **price change by X%**:

```
...
if strategy.opentrades > 0
    posPrice = strategy.opentrades.entry_price(strategy.opentrades - 1)
    if math.abs(close - posPrice) / posPrice >= change
        strategy.close("Long") // needs to match entry ID
...
```

Comment: Hi elod, thank you for your code. To clarify, what I need is a strategy where it enters the trade based on some conditions and then exits when the marketcap increases/decreases by a % from then entry point. So, if I enter where the marketcap is X, it exits when X increases/decreases by Y%

Comment: You're welcome. Basically if you store your market cap in a "cap" variable (without logic) you have more flexibility processing that value later on. You'll need to use a "lastCap" variable that you set each time you enter a position so that you know what to compare to. And that's it. I'm also editing my answer to suit your question better.

Comment: using your code I have a strategy that opens the trade but doesn't seem to close it. I just created something basic where it enters if RSI>50 and the exit code is the same as what you left above. Any ideas?

Comment: I had a mistake myself having forgotten about "var" variable declaration. The code above is corrected and working as expected. "var float lastCap = na" is necessary to store your result because the execution model of pine script to redeclare "lastCap = na" on each new bar unless you tell it not to do so. The "var" keyword makes sure that your strategy entry cap is stored as long as you override it yourself.